# Are there any good (preferably free) OO modelling apps for Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, oop, macos

I'm looking for something relatively simple to spec out a class hierarchy for C++. Can cost $ but preferably something free or at least simple and not overly feature laden and $$$.

Answer (score 2):

Once KDE4 is running really well on the Mac you should be able to use the excellent Umbrello tool.

Comment: Why would you run KDE4 on the Mac? Talk about a few steps backward.

Comment: Stephen Cox: perhaps in order to use some KDE software, like Umbrello UML modeller?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean free UML tools?  If so, I really like JUDE community edition.  The UML is certainly language agnostic, but the import/export features assume Java.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools) actually has a list of UML tools, some that should be usable on OSX.

Google found [VP UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/VPGallery/crossplatform/MacOSX.html).

Answer (score 1):

OmniGraffle does a nice job.

Comment: No, omnigraffle won't stub out code to the best of my knowledge. But the diagrams are really pretty :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Umbrello, mentioned in another answer. I have also used [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/), which is pretty good too.